# Kotlin Mockk Test breaks when using Jackson ObjectMapper in a service

Tags: kotlin, jackson, objectmapper, mockk

I needed a Jackson `ObjectMapper` in my Kotlin application. I added a `ObjectMapperConfiguration` as follows:

```
class ObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper? {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true)
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
        mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
        return mapper
    }
}
```

and extended the service declaration accordingly:

```
@Service
class CheckoutComponentService(val dcpMandatoryFieldsClient: DcpMandatoryFieldsClient, val mapper: ObjectMapper) {
...
}
```

Using the mapper works fine, for example:

```
val checkoutComponent = mapper?.readValue<CheckoutComponentResponse>(checkoutComponentString)
```

The service can be compiled and runs without problems.
But the already existing tests of the projects are failing now:
For instance a test like

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = ["management.health.rabbit.enabled=false", "management.health.binders.enabled=false"])
internal class CheckoutWebIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var restTemplate : TestRestTemplate

    @Value("\${spring.security.user.name}")
    private lateinit var name : String

    @Value("\${spring.security.user.password}")
    private lateinit var password : String

    /**
     * Tests the actuator health endpoint.
     */
    @Test
    fun testHealthEndpoint() {
        // @formatter:off
        val responseEntity: ResponseEntity<String> = this.restTemplate
                .getForEntity("/admin/health", String::class.java)
        // @formatter:on
        assertThat(responseEntity.statusCode, `is`(HttpStatus.OK))
        assertThat(responseEntity.body, hasJsonPath("$.status", equalTo("UP")))
    }
```

which has nothing to do with the changed class is broken and doesn't even start. Error message is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/KotlinReflectionInternalError

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule.setupModule(KotlinModule.kt:44)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:751)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModules(ObjectMapper.java:951)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:665)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:633)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.<init>(RestTemplate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.<init>(RestTemplate.java:191)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getSecureRestTemplate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:308)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:94)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:162)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:626)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:336)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.KotlinReflectionInternalError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 84 more
```

I guess I have to make sure the test environment knows about the ObjectMapperConfiguration but I don't know how to do that. Ansy ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@Import(ObjectMapperConfiguration.class)` to your test class as follows:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@Import(ObjectMapperConfiguration::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = ["management.health.rabbit.enabled=false", "management.health.binders.enabled=false"])
internal class CheckoutWebIntegrationTest {

    (...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks João Dias. I tried adding that annotation but I get an error right in the IntelliJ editor:
"An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant"
Autoimport feature decided to interpret that annotation as `import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I wrote it as Java code instead of Kotlin. Please check my updated answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen that but being new to Kotlin ...
It changes something, the application seems to start, I see some startup logging messages. But then later the same error message rises again. Logging starts:

:: Spring Boot ::  (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2021-11-02 18:01:29.777 ERROR [cpas-checkout,,,] 25272 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

After that the original error message is repeated in the log output.

Comment: Did it work or are you still getting the error?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.